# Is there any reliable data on what % of the UK population currently earn less than £17,300 annually?

Tags: labor-economics, statistics, wages, information

According to the Living Wage Foundation the "real living wage" in the UK is [£9 an hour](https://www.livingwage.org.uk/what-real-living-wage)

Which assuming a 37 hour week & rounding to the nearest whole GBP amounts to £17,375

> Formula used ((9*37)/7)*365.25

*I don't know how many hours a week or what the annual figure is that the LWF assumes or uses so I've had to just pick a number (37 hours a week in this instance) & calculate from there, so if anyone can provide the correct number of hours (or better yet their annual rather than hourly rate) please do.*

I've spent a fair amount of time cruising the [ONS](https://www.ons.gov.uk/) & other sites trying to come up with an accurate figure for what % of people earn less than this but simply can't find anything (so far) to provide it.

So does anyone have this figure or a site they could direct me to that has this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.gov.uk/government/statistics/percentile-points-from-1-to-99-for-total-income-before-and-after-tax/

The ONS has freely available data on the percentile points of the income distribution as estimated from the Survey of Personal Incomes. The data is collected on a yearly basis, and is currently designated as "Percentile points from 1 to 99 for total income before and after tax".

You should be able to calculate the answer to your question approximately with this information and some linear interpolation. If you really want the exact number, you probably need the actual micro-data, which I'm guessing you will need to submit a request for, unless the ONS anonymized it.

You should check whether these still need to be deflated to get real income.

Comment: Since websites change and close, please provide more to flesh out your answer. Who makes this data? What is the name of the data set? What is the source (survey?, regulatory data?)? When was it collected?